# OpenAI Gym Observation Space with Discrete and Box values

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym

I'm trying to create a custom environment for OpenAi Gym.

My observation space will have some values such as the following:

- readings:  10x  -1 to 1 continuous
- count: 0 to 1000  discrete
- on/off: 0 or 1  discrete

From the docs it seems I can create a Box with some low and high values or Discrete values or Tuples.

So if I create a Box with these 12 things (10 continuous, 2 discrete) and define it as a float32 will this still work ?   or is there a better way ?

I have tried defining it as a Dict space, but it appears this is only for GoalEnv and has a very specific set of keys.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @Rexcirus  Not to my satisfaction. In the end I used a Box with all floats. It did work.  Using multiple types and tuples seems not possible at present.

Comment: I also wanted to do this, but it appears that this is still subject of ongoing research (I found this paper which tries to combine discrete and continuous action spaces: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00449). I guess the greater problem would be that there are currently no algorithms (that I know of) which support Tuple or Dict spaces.